# Does this method create an exact duplicate? (A copy method in java)

Tags: java, testing

I have a homework to write a test for the following method in other to show that the Object and its duplicate ,which has been created using this method, are equal.

```
   /**
 * Creates a new object that is a duplicate of this instance of
 * Parameter.
 * <p>
 * The duplication is a "deep copy" in that all values contained in the
 * Parameter are themselves duplicated.
 * 
 * @return The new duplicate Parameter object.
 */
public Parameter copy( )
{
    Parameter result = new Parameter( );
    result.setName( getName( ) );
    for ( int index = 0; index < getNumberOfValues( ); index++ )
    {
        result.addValue( getValue( index ).copy( ) );
    }
    return result;
 }
```

I wrote different methods, but each time the result shows that they are not equal. One of my tests:

```
@Test
public void testCopy() {
    Parameter param = new Parameter();
    Value val1 = new Value();
    //val1.setName("Hi!");
    //param.addValue(val1);

    Parameter param2 = param.copy();
    Parameter expected = param;
    Parameter actual = param2;

    assertEquals(param, param2);
}
```

But it seems that this method doesn't create and exact duplicate of param. 
Would you please guide me?

And this is the copy method for value:

```
   /**
 * Creates a new Value object that is a duplicate of this instance.
 * 
 * @return The new duplicate Value object.
 */
public Value copy( )
{
    Value newValue = new Value( );
    newValue.setName( getName( ) );
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: Did you rewrite equals()?

Comment: Is your copy method for the Value class similar to your clone method in Parameter? I mean, creating a new instance and assigning the value to the new object.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the fact that it shows these two objects are not equal is proof that OP actually did make a deep copy rather than a shallow copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Parameter class needs an equals method(). Without this java runs equality based on reference(the default behavior of Object.equals() ), hence your observation.

Your equals method may look like:

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    Parameter p = (Parameter)o;
    return this.getName().equals(p.getNames) && this.getNumberOfValues() == p.getNumberOfValues() &&B this.values().equals(p.values());
}
```

Comment: It already *has* an equals() method inherited from Object; the OP needs to override it.

Answer (score 0):

The equals method for the class `Object` ([described here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)) states clearly that the references need to the refer to the same object in order to return true. In your case, the copy method correctly creates a new Parameter and afterwards a new Value in order to create the copy object. Hence, the existing `equals()` method will always return false.

In order to correctly test, you need to do what the comments stated, that is, create a new equals() method that will override the existing one in the Object class, both in the Parameter and in the Value classes. Your method should test whether the **content** (the name, in each object) of each object is the same, or any other semantic that you will deem fit according to your application.